# c# - Создание объекта Application

Tags: c#, .net

Когда связываю приложения с Excel файлом, сперва создаю объект класса Application. Почти всегда сперва `using _Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;` а потом `_Excel.Application excel = new _Excel.Application();` . Сегодня заметил что если даже не писать _Excel,( т.е просто писать `Application excel = new Application()`) все нормально работает.

Я так понимаю что существует другие приложения которые запускаются через `Application`, из за этого указать `_Excel` предпочтительно. Но, не уверен в этом. Можете полностью объяснить, почему такое указание существует, если через `Application` можно все сделать ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `Application`, помимо `Excel`, встречается, как минимум, в объектных моделях различных приложений `Office` и везде выполняет одну и ту же задачу.

Если Вы работаете только с одним приложением, вызывать метод `Application` сам по себе ещё допустимо. Но, если Вам потребуется два таких приложения и более, из-за такого стиля обращения к этому методу возникнет конфликт.

Поэтому, ИМХО, лучше перестраховаться и всегда указывать приложение явно. Заодно это облегчит понимание Вашего кода другими разработчиками или даже Вами самим после возвращения к данному проекту спустя некоторое время.